# How to put the View dynamicaly between two LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have putting such data into LinearView. as like below code:

```
public void showResult()
{
    //db.open();
    //c2 = db.getAllTitles(table_name);

    List<TextView> textListWord = new ArrayList<TextView>(tempEmployerList.size());
    List<TextView> textListAnswer = new ArrayList<TextView>(tempEmployerList.size());
    List<TextView> imageListAnswer = new ArrayList<TextView>(tempEmployerList.size());

    //for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)

    //int limit = tempEmployerList.size(); 

    for(int i = 0; i<=tempEmployerList.size()-1; i++)
    {    
        RelativeLayout innerLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        innerLayout.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        // set the Multiple TextView
        TextView qWordTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        TextView aWordTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        TextView aImageView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        qWordTV.setText("\n"+"1");
        qWordTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        qWordTV.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
        qWordTV.setPadding(3, 0, 0, 0);

        aWordTV.setText("\n"+"2");
        aWordTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        aWordTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        aWordTV.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);    
        aWordTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        aWordTV.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);
        aWordTV.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);


        aImageView.setText("\n"+"3");
        aImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        aImageView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        aImageView.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        aImageView.setPadding(0, 0, 9, 0);


        /**** Any other text view setup code ****/    

        innerLayout.addView(qWordTV);
        innerLayout.addView(aWordTV);
        innerLayout.addView(aImageView);

        myLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);

        textListWord.add(qWordTV); 
        textListAnswer.add(aWordTV);
        imageListAnswer.add(aImageView);

    } 
    //while (limit==0);

}
```

Now i want to create the Simple View dynamicaly here. . .
As like:

```
<View android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#FF000000" />
```

in xml.

Now how to make such View like line dynamicaly ?
Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View line = new View(getApplicationContext());
line.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
// You may need to convert dip to px here, raw pixels are used in the example:
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2);
line.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Yes i am able to create the line but its vertical. I want the line as Horizontal.

Comment: Just swap the arguments in `LayoutParams(width, height)` constructor. I've updated my answer - you can use it now.

Comment: Thanks it works but still i got some problem. Let me update my question.

Comment: Ok just tell me is it possible to set the Gravity to the dynamicaly created LinearLayout ?

Comment: [LinearLayout.setGravity(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity(int))

Comment: Or did you mean [LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html.gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity)?